# Nested mini-app with own router

Tags: reactjs, nested, react-router-v4

I have a web-app that has basically another mini-app (that lives inside a sidebar, drawer, etc) inside of it that needs its own navigation independent of the main app and does not affect the URL or browser History; but they need to share a redux store because changes in either need to be sychronised.

```
<BrowserHistory>
    <ConnectedSwitchWithRouter>
        <Header />
        {/*
            <Route/>s
        *}
        <Footer>
            {/*
                Mini-app here
            */}
        </Footer>
    </ConnectedSwitchWithRouter>
</BrowserHistory>
```

First, is this possible?

I'm thinking the mini-app in might be able to use MemoryRouter, but I'm wondering how updating the mini-apps route would work. Can I use `<Link>`?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out yes, that works exactly as I expected. For navigation, I used `onClick` and `props.history.push()`.